# Android AppCompat ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I want to style all the `android.app.ProgressDialog`s in my app on pre-Lollipop versions to make them look like Material Design.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious: I'm looking for `android.support.v7.app.ProgressDialog`, but there is no such class in Android AppCompat library.

Should I write my own implementation of `ProgressDialog` from scratch? What is the reason it's not included in AppCompat library?

Answer (score 5):

`Widget.AppCompat.*` styles can be used starting from API 7.

There is currently no AppCompat style for the progress dialog since it relies on AnimatedVectorDrawable.

However, it's possible to write a custom `drawable` that has the same behavior and apply it to your `ProgressDialog`.

check out [GIT](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/882ee91503f28d1fd60ba939c5b37db6b9d4ad29/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/src/java/android/support/v4/widget/MaterialProgressDrawable.java)

Answer (score 3):

You can use other cool compatibility libraries besides AppCompat. 
There are cool libraries which brings fully animated Material Design components to pre-Lolipop Android on Github. The images are from [Rey5137's "Material" library](https://github.com/rey5137/material). You better use one of such libraries rather that writing from scratch.

[image: material loading icon]
[image]